# MYSQL Cannot Create Table: Error 150

Tags: mysql, ddl

I am trying to create some tables with foreign keys, however I cannot get past error 150. It also says error 1005 cannot create table Aliases.

Here is my script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Aliases`;
CREATE TABLE `Aliases` (
  `aliasnum` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `usernum` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `display` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `selected` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aliasnum`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_DISPLAY` (`usernum`,`address`,`display`),
  KEY `IX_USERNUM` (`usernum`),
  KEY `IX_USERNUM_ADDRESS` (`usernum`,`address`),
  CONSTRAINT `Aliases_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usernum`, `address`) REFERENCES `Mailboxes` (`usernum`, `address`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 MAX_ROWS=4294967295 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=100 COMMENT='Store mailbox display aliases and default status information.';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Mailboxes`;
CREATE TABLE `Mailboxes` (
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `usernum` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`address`),
  KEY `IX_USERNUM` (`usernum`),
  KEY `IX_USERNUM_ADDRESS` (`usernum`,`address`),
  CONSTRAINT `Mailboxes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usernum`) REFERENCES `Users` (`usernum`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 MAX_ROWS=4294967295 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=100 COMMENT='All mailboxes for which we accept e-mail.';
```

The error says its line 29 which is:

```
`selected` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

All tables are InnoDB. I am really stuck and not sure what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first table has a constraint which refers to the second one.  So switch the order of creation.

Of course, your second table has a constraint which refers to some other table `Users` you didn't mention in your question.  So, you'll have to create `Users` first, then `Mailboxes`, then `Aliases`.

Or, you can remove the `CONSTRAINT` clauses from your table definitions, then create your constraints later after your tables are all available, like this.

```
CREATE TABLE Users
CREATE TABLE Aliases ...
CREATE TABLE Mailboxes ...

ALTER TABLE Aliases ADD
  CONSTRAINT `Aliases_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usernum`, `address`) REFERENCES `Mailboxes` (`usernum`, `address`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE Mailboxes ADD
  CONSTRAINT `Mailboxes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usernum`) REFERENCES `Users` (`usernum`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

(I think Line 29 isn't relevant.)

Comment: Ohh I feel so dumb, sorted now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. There's no dumb questions except the ones you don't ask.  And, MySQL does give strange line numbers in error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
CONSTRAINT `Aliases_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usernum`, `address`) REFERENCES `Mailboxes` (`usernum`, `address`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

And

```
CONSTRAINT `Mailboxes_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`usernum`) REFERENCES `Users` (`usernum`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

in the `create table` command.

Add `FOREIGN KEY` after creating tables

```
ALTER TABLE `Aliases` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `Aliases_fk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`usernum`, `address`) 
REFERENCES `Mailboxes` (`usernum`, `address`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And

```
ALTER TABLE `Mailboxes`
ADD CONSTRAINT `Mailboxes_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`usernum`)
REFERENCES `Users` (`usernum`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer was helpful as well!